# Matrix-scalar chain rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus

$A(x)$ is a matrix-valued function, $x$ is a scalar, and $f(x)$ is a function that maps a scalar to another scalar.

Does that mean $\frac{\partial A(f(x))}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial A(f(x))}{\partial f(x)}\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}$?

Comment: Define what you mean with each of your objects.
From the middle one I reckon $A$ is not a matrix, but a matrix-valued function that depends on a real value, i.e. $A:\mathbb{R}\to \mathcal{M}_{m\times n}\mathbb{R}$.
But the others I don't know.

Comment: Where $\mathcal{M}_{m\times n} \mathbb{R}$ is the set of $m\times n$ matrices with real entries.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz A(x) maps a scalar to a matrix.

Comment: Your second "=" is supposed to be a multiplication?

Comment: @hamsteronwheels: How do you define $\partial A(x) / \partial f(x)$?